# Is it possible to apply a fade transition on sending children toFront() inside StackPane?

Tags: javafx-8

I'm somewhat to new to JavaFX (coming from Swing) and have a tendency to use StackPanes with several fxml subpanels inside, a different one of of which is brought toFront() on a certain button click or menu selection. Is it possible to animate this with a fade-out / fade-in transition? I've been googling for a couple of days but can't find anything related to this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

[`toFront()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#toFront--) works simply by moving the node to the end of its parent's child list (the order of the child list determines the z-order). So the "frontmost node" is just the one at the end of the list. You can create an observable value containing this node using a combination of [`Bindings.valueAt(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#valueAt-javafx.collections.ObservableList-javafx.beans.value.ObservableIntegerValue-) and [`Bindings.size(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#size-javafx.collections.ObservableList-).

```
ObjectBinding<Node> frontNode = Bindings.valueAt(stackPane.getChildren(), 
    Bindings.size(stackPane.getChildren()).subtract(1));
```

Or, for an alternative implementation:

```
ObjectBinding<Node> frontNode = new ObjectBinding<Node>() {

    { bind(stackPane.getChildren()); }

    @Override
    protected Node computeValue() {
        if (stackPane.getChildren().isEmpty()) return null ;
        return stackPane.getChildren().get(stackPane.getChildren().size() - 1) ;
    }
}
```

Then you can just register a listener which fades the old value out and fades the new value in. The following should give you a starting point from which you can work.

```
frontNode.addListener((obs, oldNode, newNode) -> {
    SequentialTransition fadeOutIn = new SequentialTransition();
    if (oldNode != null) {
        FadeTransition fadeOut = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(1), oldNode);
        fadeOut.setToValue(0);
        fadeOutIn.getChildren().add(fadeOut);
    }
    if (newNode != null) {
        FadeTransition fadeIn = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(1), newNode);
        fadeIn.setFromValue(0);
        fadeIn.setToValue(1);
        fadeOutIn.getChildren().add(fadeIn);
    }
    fadeOutIn.play();
});
```

Depending on how things are set up in your application, you may need to initialize the opacity of all the stack pane's children to zero.

Note that all this code needs is a reference to the stack pane.

Comment: Thank you very much for that code, though it took me a while to figure it out. Like I said, I'm still pretty new to JavaFX. However, I tried it this way and it didn't work consistently. On some runs, all the toFronts inside the button handlers would trigger the listener and the fades worked, but on other runs, it would stop working after one or two buttons were clicked.

Comment: Dang, comments are too short, to continue from above:

So i took the idea and implemented it at the controller level where the buttons are handled, setting up fadeIn and fadeOut at the class level and using them inside each button action (since now the children already start with opacity 0). All that was needed extra was a reference to the current child node so it could be faded out before fading in the new one. Oh, and also, the fadeIn had to be put inside a fadeOut.setOnFinished handler (which ends in fadeOut.setOnFinished(null) to cancel the handler).

Comment: @Joe1962 "On other runs, it would stop working after one or two button clicks". You are probably running into [this](http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2015/02/10/the-trouble-with-weak-listeners.html). If you make the `frontNode`  binding an instance variable, instead of a local variable, it should fix it.